# Can I set the "Endpoint Override URL" to a presigned POST URL in NiFi's PutS3Object processor?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I recently learned that it's possible to generate a presigned *upload* URL for a client to upload to S3.

It is possible to set this URL as the value of "Endpoint Override URL" in the PutS3Object processor's settings – probably through a FlowFile attribute and ExpLang reference – and then PutS3Object use that URL in its entirety, disregarding any other settings that would differ from what that presigned URL provides?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I don't think it would work. `Endpoint Override URL` is mainly used for providing alternate endpoints (that are S3 compatible), such as VPC (Virtual Private Cloud).

However, what you can do is, instead of using `PutS3Object`, you can use `InvokeHTTP` and configure `Remote URL` with the pre-signed URL and using appropriate HTTP method.

One thing to keep in mind:

- The Pre-signed URL comes up with an Object key pre-existing so when you keep on writing to the same pre-signed url, the value of the Object gets overwritten.